# The target "Build" does not exist in the project - Visual Studio - SQL

Tags: sql, visual-studio, target, build-error, test-data

I have a database solution in `Visual Studio` that was 2015, I have just upgraded the solution to use `Visual Studio 2017`.

Now when I try to build the project that holds all the test data, it fails with this error.

> > The target "Build" does not exist in the project

Everything I have found online so far has not worked.

When I build the Database project and deploy locally that works fine, its just the test data section.

Hope this makes some sense - I'm only a junior!

Comment: Can you run through steps how you have deployed in new visual studio ?, what u mean by database solution

Comment: I can think of a simple solution to add project files manually